# Sort multi-dimensional array with custom function depending on depth

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I'm trying to sort a multi-dimensional array based the current active depth of the sorting function.  If it was sorting the first array it came into contact with, the active depth would be 0.  If the sorting the second, it would be 1, and so on and so forth.

My basic array structure is as follows:

```
$arr[$year][$monthName][$dayNumber] = $somelink;
```

I am generating the array using regular expressions in a for loop of file-names.. That part isn't what's important.

As to the specifics of the array structure.. `$year` is a numeric value, such as 2012 or 2013, `$monthName` is the name of a month, such as April or March, `$dayNumber` is of course the number of the day, zero-padded, and finally, `$somelink` contains html markup, which isn't really important at the moment.

Getting into the actual question.. a part of this script I'm not going to show(unless requested), uses the current structure of the array to create a list-based menu.  Starting today, the script started acting strange; April was appearing before March, and the day 16 before 1.  I tried to fix this with the function below to little avail; I can't really.. figure out the logic to get this to work.

The expected output is for the years to be lowest-to-highest, starting from the top, the months to be sorted the same way, though by their number instead of their name, and days to be sorted the same way as years.  The last link doesn't really matter here, I don't plan on sorting that.

Expected output illustrated(links not shown to keep this short):

```
2012
 |--March
      |-1
      |-15
      |-16
 |--April
 |--May
2013
 |--March
      |-1
 |--April
      |-1
      |-15
      |-16
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```php
function mon_sort($a,$b) {
    if (date("n",strtotime($a)) == date("n",strtotime($b))) { return 0; }
    return (date("n",strtotime($a)) > date("n",strtotime($b)) ? 1 : -1);
}
function menu_sort($arr,$depth) {
    $newarr = array();
    if ($depth == 0) {
        ksort($arr);
    }
    else if ($depth == 1) {
        uksort($arr,'mon_sort');
    }
    else {

    }
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $depth++;
            $value = menu_sort($value,$depth);
        }
        $newarr[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $newarr;
}
```

I should also note as per the `mon_sort()` function, that the 1:-1 in the ternary operator doesn't quite matter, as I've tried it both ways and it fails each time, so that can't be the problem.

In case in the above, I didn't really.. ask a question, I'm wondering what I've done wrong here, and what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: Is the requirement that it be done as an array? Or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: @FloatingRock Well, I loop through the array to create the menu.. if you have a method of creating a nested list without an array, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your function to sort in-place, same way as `ksort` and `uksort` does

```
function mon_sort($a,$b) {
    if (date("n",strtotime($a)) == date("n",strtotime($b))) { return 0; }
    return (date("n",strtotime($a)) > date("n",strtotime($b)) ? 1 : -1);
}
function menu_sort(&$arr,$depth = 0) {
    if ($depth == 1) {
        uksort($arr,'mon_sort');
    } else {
        ksort($arr);
    }
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            menu_sort($value,$depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```